# Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.

Tags: typescript

I have function in ts

```
 export function minutesToHoursAndMinutes(m, zeroPadded) {
    if (zeroPadded == null) { zeroPadded = false; }
    let hours:any = Math.floor(m / 60);
    if (zeroPadded && (`${hours}`.length === 1)) { hours = `0${hours}`; }
    let minutes:any = m % 60;
    if (zeroPadded && (`${minutes}`.length === 1)) { minutes = `0${minutes}`; }
    if ((hours === 24) && (minutes === '00')) {
      hours = 23;
      minutes = 59;
    }
    return [hours, minutes];
  };
```

And try to use it like this

```
if (("#t-time-range").length > 0) {
$("#t-time-range").slider({
  range: "min",
  value: filter_max.max_traveltime,
  min: filter_max.min_traveltime,
  max: filter_max.max_traveltime+15,
  step: 15,
  slide(event, ui) {
    const hms = FilterFunctions.minutesToHoursAndMinutes(ui.value );
    $("#t-time").val(`Max ${hms[0]}t ${hms[1]}m`);
    return $('#filter_travel_time').val(ui.value);
  }
});
const hms = FilterFunctions.minutesToHoursAndMinutes($("#t-time-range").slider("value"));
$("#t-time").val(`Max ${hms[0]}t ${hms[1]}m`);
$('#filter_travel_time').val($("#t-time-range").slider("value"));
```

}

But I have error about argues

Like this

> Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.

How I can make 2 argument optional?

Comment: `FilterFunctions.minutesToHoursAndMinutes(ui.value )`  what?

Comment: `FilterFunctions.minutesToHoursAndMinutes($("#t-time-range").slider("value"))`  you are only giving these two calls one argument ...

Comment: I know, but can I make second argue optional? @Taplar

Comment: You can just pass in `null` as the second parameter or change `zeroPadded` to `zeroPadded?` in the type signature

Comment: You could also take the zeroPadded off of the method definition and the cases where you want to use it just reference `arguments[1]`

Comment: Did you do any research? https://www.google.com/search?q=typescript+make+argument+optional

Comment: Do something like this `export function minutesToHoursAndMinutes(m, zeroPadded = null )`

Answer (score 0):

try changing the last property of your slider object to

```
slide: function(event, ui) {
    const hms = FilterFunctions.minutesToHoursAndMinutes(ui.value );
    $("#t-time").val(`Max ${hms[0]}t ${hms[1]}m`);
    return $('#filter_travel_time').val(ui.value);
}
```

Comment: `minutesToHoursAndMinutes` still expects two arguments

Comment: Try passing false as an argument during the 2 invocations and removing the first line

    if (zeroPadded == null) { zeroPadded = false; }

from the minutesToHoursAndMinutes function.

Comment: So your solution (hidden in the comments) to the problem is: "Pass two arguments"

Comment: Considering that the rest of the snippet is already pure spaghetti...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps setting a default value such as

`export function minutesToHoursAndMinutes(m, zeroPadded=null)`.

This way the value is already set, and if you do not pass an argument, it will default to the null value.

Answer (score 0):

`?` makes argument optional. [Reference](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters).
`export function minutesToHoursAndMinutes(m, zeroPadded?) {`